# Would questions on whole cell modeling get answers at this site?

Tags: discussion

I am self-learning about whole cell modeling, specifically [An introduction to whole-cell modeling](http://intro-to-wc-modeling.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#) and [Fundamentals of Systems Biology: From Synthetic Circuits to Whole-cell Models](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1420084100). While my background is decades of programming, for cellular biology it is only skimming through a few books. While I can ask the authors and research groups questions directly I would prefer to only ask them specific questions and get answers to more general topic questions related to whole cell modeling elsewhere; e.g. if I ask about [BioNetGen](http://www.csb.pitt.edu/Faculty/Faeder/?page_id=409) that would general, but asking how to tie BioNetGen in with other software and methodologies specific to the groups would be to specific for here.

So are there people at this site who can answer questions about whole cell modeling in general?

Comment: Could you give a more specific example? It sounds like it would likely be on topic but since it isn't my field, I can't be sure from your description. But as a general rule, asking about using bioinformatics tools and/or frameworks is on topic, yes.

Comment: @terdon I don't have any specific questions now, but if I do I will ask in the regular site. I did have one specific question but figured it out, e.g. Can someone compare and contrast BNGL (BioNetGen Language) with SBML (System Biology Markup Lanague)?

Comment: @GuyCoder that would be a nice question to have, remember that you can self answer your questions too. (And I would like to know the answer to that question without digging the formatting descriptions ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess it will depend on the question. I  would expect it to be on topic, in principle, so give it a go!